# Can’t get to standard form of linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As I was solving my homework; I was stuck at numbers 2 and 6. This is a linear ODE.

2. $(y+1)dx + (4x-y)dy = 0$

Divided it by $dx$:

$$(y+1) + (4x-y)dy/dx = 0$$

Transposed the $(y+1)$

$$(4x-y)dy/dx = -(y+1)$$

Divided it by $(4x-y)$

$$dy/dx = -(y+1)/(4x-y)$$

And that is the farthest I can go. It is impossible to bring it to the standard form.

For number 6:

$$3xdy/dx=2y(x-3)$$

The farthest I can go is:

$$dy/dx = (2y/3x^2) - (6y/3x^3).$$

The rest of the problems were easily solved but those 2 are very hard to bring to the standard form.

PS: I can’t use the tag “linear-differential-equation” and “homework-exercises”. Was forced to use “ordinary-differential-equations”.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 2 to be a linear ode then you need to consider $x$ as a function of $y$ instead.

i.e. instead of 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{y+1}{4x-y}$$
you can write
$$\frac{dx}{dy} = -\frac{4x-y}{y+1} =  -\frac{4x}{y+1}+ \frac{y}{y+1} $$
which is of the form
$$ x'(y) = f(y)x + g(y).$$

You seem to be basically done for 6, you have it in the form $y = f(x)y$ which also shows its a homogeneous equation.

Comment: 2. I am realy sorry but tbh; I don’t understand what you mean by “consider x as a funtion of y”.

Comment: I mean switch the roles of x and y. If $x=x(y)$ is the function and $y$ is the variable, then the standard form would be $x'= f(y)x + g(y)$. The presence of the $ydy$ term indicates that it's not a linear equation in $y$ @Bido262

Comment: Can you post an answer? Having a hard time in changing the roles of variables.

Comment: @Bido262 I'll do as you wish, but its literally as I said, and I don't think seeing me write it will help if you don't understand what I said. How about you try to explain what is hard to you?

Comment: For number 6; it should be answered using linear differential equations. We haven’t tackled homogenous yet.

Comment: @Bido262 sorry, but I cant understand you; "linear differential equations" is not a technique that can solve things. I don't know if you know, but separable ODEs are special cases of linear ODEs. The only content of your question, as far as I am aware, is to show that the equations can be put in standard form. This is a matter of definitions and doesn't need anything other than elementary algebra. Also, you are free to ignore what I said about homogeneous equations (or take 10 seconds to Google what it means)

Answer (score 1):

for Nr. 2 is not linear, since it contain y*y'  so you can not bring it to standard form but with $$\frac{dx}{dy}$$
 you have $$ \frac{dx}{dy}+\frac{4}{y+1}*x=\frac{y}{y+1}$$
Nr 6 you should see?
trula

Comment: You should edit your earlier answer instead of posting a second one

Answer (score 1):

The second problem is given as $$(y+1)dx+(4x−y)dy=0$$

if you divide by $dy$ instead of $dx$ then you will form

$$(y+1)\frac{dx}{dy}=-4x+y$$

which simplifies to

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\Big(\frac{-4}{y+1}\Big)x+\frac{y}{y+1}$$

or

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=f(y)x+g(y)$$

which is a first-order linear ordinary differential equation.

The sixth problem is given as

$$3x\frac{dy}{dx}=2y(x-3)$$

where rearranging leads to

$$\frac{1}{2y}dy=\frac{x-3}{3x}dx$$

or

$$\frac{1}{2y}dy=\Big(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{x}\Big)dx$$

which can be solved by techniques which are known to you.

Comment: For number 6 I no longer need to use linesr differential equation techniques right? Since it is separable.

Comment: You can directly integrate both sides after reducing it to the above form.

Answer (score 0):

2. ist not a linear ODE, what would you consider a "standard form"

   6. 3/=2(−3) is a linear ODE 
      dy/y= (x-3)/3x* dx
      trula

Comment: 2. What I mean standard form is: dy/dx +p(x)y = f(x). It is impossible to bring it to its standard form; can’t proceed in finding y.